# Swift Xcode Files folder is not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I've just created an Xcode project for the first time and now I want to
learn the Swift programming language with the help of a Udemy course.
Unfortunately, my files folder on the left side of the Xcode window is shown very differently than in the Udemy tutorial. I will just attach 2 screenshots in the attachment.
For example, in the tutorial, the instructor has a "main.swift" file that he opens, but I don't have it.

I would be really happy about an answer and help!

With love

[image]
Tim[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when he created a new project he created a Command Line Tool project from the template menu. Generate a new project via Xcode > New > Project > macOS > Command Line Tool instead.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like they are using SwiftUI. Try this:

File -> New -> Swift Package